# Visual studio code. Как настроить автообновление браузера?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Как настроить автообновление браузера? Есть ли какие-то аналоги live reload?..

Comment: под галпом live-reload вообще изумительно работает , даже подключаются все апараты в wifi сети

Comment: В данный момент пользуюсь Live Server https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer

Answer (score 1):

Установить программу http://livereload.com/

Установить плагин для браузера в моем случае для хрома https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei?hl=ru

1. Запускаем программу livereload
2. Выбираем папку с файлами за которыми будете отслеживать изменения
3. Открыть в браузере страницу вашего сайта и нажать в верхнем правом углу на значек  livereload. Если livereload плагин активен, то внутри него закрашенная темная точка.

Все. Без галпа и всего прочего у вас будут обновляться страницы при изменении файлов. При изменении css обновление происходит без перезагрузки страницы.

Answer (score 1):

Самый быстрый способ:

1. Заходите в расширения (ctrl+shift+x);
2. В поиске пишите Live Server;
3. Устанавливаете расширение;
4. Перезагружаете VS Code.

Можно пользоваться. Открываете папку с проектом, нажимаете внизу Go Live или пкм + Open with Live Server.

Преимущества именно сервера объяснять думаю не нужно.